# Xcode localize a string in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, string, swift, localization

I am trying to localize a string list. I have some photos, and for every photo a description of that, and I want to translate the description in another language.
That's the code:

ViewController.swift

```
var imageList:[String] = ["new_york_city_sky_house_skyscraper_59212_640x1136.jpg","79506M1pZO4U6d12i0Xzf27765gWo71P5061732uthh68xHQ8Dq1yTQ0Bj8p9F45.jpg","iphone 5 wallpaper new york.jpg","New-York-Vintage-Effect-iphone-5-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com.jpg","Superb-View-Over-New-York-iphone-5-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com.jpg","New-York-Empire-State-Building-1136x640.jpg","New-York-City-iphone-5s-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com.jpg","new-york-city.jpg","New-York-By-Day-iphone-5-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com.jpg","The-Empire-State-Building-New-York-1136x640.jpg"]

var nameList:[String] = ["NYC","New York", "Empire State Building","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]

var sentMessage: [String] = ["NYC 1", "New York 2", "Empire State Building 3", "Description here 4", "Description here 5", "Description here 6", "Description here 7", "Description here 8", "Description here 9", "Description here 10"]

let minimages = 0
let maximages = 9
var imageIndex : NSInteger = 0

@IBAction func showView(){
    let vc = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
    vc.sentMessage = sentMessage[imageIndex]
    showViewController(vc, sender: self)
```

SecondViewController.swift

```
@IBOutlet var myMessage : UILabel?
var sentMessage: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myMessage?.text = sentMessage
```

I'd like to translate namelist category and sent message category, like this: "Description here 1" in "Descrizione qui 1", "Description here 2" in "Descrizione qui 2"...

What can I do? I am learning by myself to create an app because I have got some ideas, but I am stucked here... Thank you!

Comment: Can you be more specific in the question, and on the result that you expect?

Comment: I'd like to translate the items in the arrays called nameList and sentMessage from English to Italian.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i

Answer (score -1):

Ciao Matteo

**Localize-Swift** is a simple framework that improves i18n and localization in Swift iOS apps - providing cleaner syntax and in-app language switching.

Install it by adding the following on your Podfile

> pod 'Localize-Swift', '~> 1.6'

Read [its Gitpage](https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift) for detailed information